# How do I access individual fields in a .TXT file formatted like a .CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a **members.txt** file, which is formatted like a CSV but is required to be saved as a TXT file.

```
John,Smith,11
Jim,Samuel,15
Elena,Larson,88
Harriet,Patterson,63
Roy,Horton,32
```

I need to be able to access an individual field, such as printing off only the forenames. I want the output to look like this:

```
John
Jim
Elena
Harriet
Roy
```

Here is my python file at the moment

```
text_file = open("members.txt","r")
lines_in_file = text_file.read().splitlines()
for line_entry in lines_in_file:
    print(line_entry[2])
```

And this is the output. I have noticed it sliced the string by the first character, instead of extracting the first column

```
J
J
E
H
R
```

Comment: The `csv` module functions don't care what name/extension your file has, so I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the rows generated by `csv.reader` and unpack the first name as the first item in each row:

```
import csv
with open("members.txt") as file:
    for first_name, *_ in csv.reader(file):
        print(first_name)
```

Comment: okay but instead of `csv.reader(open("members.txt"))`, a `with` context block should be used

Comment: i like the `first_name, *_` trick, though. your answer saves the question from future deletion...

Comment: Sure, updated as suggested then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to split your string on a chosen delimeter.

```
text_file = open("members.txt","r")

for line in text_file:
    print(line.split(",")[0])
```

Comment: You could just eliminate the `.read().splitlines()`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I've changed it.